# Koleria stem is hardening from bottom eventually killing whole plant

Tags: pests, fungus, roots, stems

I am very upset for so long time. Some of my kohlerias die before even had the chance to buildup buds. Very stall in growth. Some doing well, still stalling in growth though. Starts from direct below soil line. Stem shrinks a little, becoming redbrownish. Leaves dropping, drying leaves from below to top, plant dying. Stem then is hard and somewhat dry? Roots dry. Why does this happen? I see it more in younger plants. Does this starts from the roots, so stem cant get enough nutritiens up to the leaves? Once I sliced the stem longwise, it was hollow!fungus?thank you. Any advise appreciated. Happens to my gardenia too. Stiff, harden stem, drying plant.

any advice appreciated.

[image]
thank you

[image]

[image]

Comment: Round up the usual suspects. Any heat vent nearby? Too much or too little water? Fertilizer? Any insect or fungus?

Comment: Thank you. None of them. But was near heater in winter hence window is there also. 1 gardenia was in not heated kitchen. Both died.

Comment: Did I mention, leaves becoming brown and dry from button up. Stems lower part then looks bold and ugly.